# How to make django querysets with dynamic filters?

Tags: django, django-views

So basically I have a website in Django that is a storefront and the end user has three filters to use.  A product type filter (pants, shoes, shirts, etc), a delivery filter (yes/no), and a location/popularity filter.

Currently in my views.py I have this method.

```
if request.is_ajax():
    if request.GET.get('filter') == 'shirts':
        latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype="shirts")
        context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
        return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)
    if request.GET.get('filter') == 'pants':
        latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype="pants")
        context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
        return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)
    if request.GET.get('filter') == 'shoes':
        latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype="shoes")
        context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
        return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)
```

As you can see, this handles the first filter.  The problem I'm having is if I select, let's say 'pants', it filters by pants but disregards what was selected in the other two filters.  Another example, let's say I select pants, the page populates with the results of that filter.  But if I then go to the delivery filter and select "Yes", the page populates with items that are only deliverable, but the "pants" filter is forgotten.

What I'm trying to figure how is how to create a queryset in my views that remembers the other two querysets (if that makes sense).

The only way I can think of to do this is to create True/False flags for each value in each filter, and then add probably 100 lines of if/then statements checking each flag.  There has got to be a better way.

UPDATE:

This is how I am passing the filter value from my template.

```
function filter(type) {
  $.get("/storefront/?filter="+type, function(data) {
     var $data = data;
     $('.grid').children().remove();
     $('.grid').append( $data ).masonry( 'appended', $data, true ).masonry( 'layout' ); 
  });
}


  //Product Filter    
$("#shirts").unbind().click(function () { 
  filter("shirts");
  return false;
});


$("#pants").unbind().click(function () { 
  filter("pants");
  return false;
});

$("#shoes").unbind().click(function () { 
  filter("shoes");
  return false;
});



  //Delivery Filter
$("#deliveryyes").unbind().click(function () { 
  filter("deliveryyes");
  return false;
});

$("#deliveryno").unbind().click(function () { 
  filter("deliveryno");
  return false;
});
```

In my views.py, this will not work:

```
 entry_types = request.GET.getlist('filter')
 latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype__in=entry_types)
```

Because I will need to filter by entrytype('pants', 'shirts', shoes') AND deliveryoption ('deliveryyes', 'deliveryno').  Each filter has it's own column in my model.

```
models.py

class Entry(models.Model):
    headline= models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='entryauthors')
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    zipcode =models.IntegerField(null=True, max_length=10)
    !!! entrytype = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10)
    !!! deliveryoption=models.CharField(null=True, max_length=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the comma-separated list of the `filter` values:

```
/mylist/filter=shirts,pants
```

And then get entries using the [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup:

```
entry_types = request.GET.get('filter', '').split(',')
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype__in=entry_types)
```

Or use the the `getlist()` method of the `QueryDict`:

```
/mylist/filter=shirts&filter=pants
```

With the same ORM call:

```
entry_types = request.GET.getlist('filter')
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype__in=entry_types)
```

**UPDATE**: To pass the multiple types to the view save them in the array and use `join()` method to get the comma-separated string of them:

```
var types = []; // currently shown entry types

function filter(type) {
  // add or remove the items from the grid
  var index = types.indexOf(type);
  if (index > -1) {
    types.splice(index, 1); // remove the type from the list
  } else {
    types.push(type); // add the type to the filter
  }
  $.get("/storefront/?filter="+types.join(","), function(data) {
    ...
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: If you use two fields to filter the queryset then you have to create two separate lists in your view:

```
filters = request.GET.getlist('filter')
entry_types = [f for f in filters if not f.startswith('delivery')]
delivery_types = [f for f in filters if f.startswith('delivery')]

latest_entries = Entry.objects.all()
if entry_types:
    latest_entries = latest_entries.filter(entrytype__in=entry_types)
if delivery_types:
    latest_entries = latest_entries.filter(deliverytype__in=delivery_types)
```

JavaScript code will work without any touches.

Comment: I'm not sure how to pass the the values of more than one filter in the first place.  I updated my post and included some code from the template.

Comment: Save the list of types in the array in the global scope and change this array from your `click` events.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Okay, I think I am going to go this route that you have suggested.  I have an additional question about how to add/remove from the types array in javascript.  I Will update OP in a second..

Comment: Okay, any chance you could explain the javascript you posted above?  Specifically, I'm not understanding how to remove the filters from the array such as shirts, pants, when you click on shoes?

Comment: Also, I updated my post, if you look at the bottom of it, you can see my models.py  I have separate columns in my db table for 'entrytype' and 'deliveryoption'.  Doesn't that mean Entry.objects.filter(entrytype__in=entry_types) won't work?

Comment: Your if statement in Update 2 will only return objects with the delivery filter or entry type filter, not both at the same time.

Comment: Unless I'm just not understanding it.

Comment: It filters for both conditions.  `filter` calls are chained so if `entry_types` and `delivery_types` are not empty then the queryset will be equivalent of `Entry.objects.filter(entrytype__in=entry_types, deliverytype__in=delivery_types)`

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly valid for a parameter to show up multiple times in a request. Use [`QueryDict.getlist()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to get a list containing all values.

```
http://example.com/?foo=12&foo=34
```

...

```
print >>sys.stderr, request.GET.getlist('foo')
```